# Haskell program hangs when mixing compiled and interpreted code

Tags: haskell, runtime-error, ghc

Consider the following trivial modules:

```
module Fail1 where
identity x = x

module Main where
import Fail1
main = print (identity 7)
```

I save these as `Fail1.hs` and `Fail2.hs`. If I try to run this program, all is well:

```
> runhaskell Fail2
7
```

But take a look at this:

```
> ghc -O2 --make Fail1
[1 of 1] Compiling Fail1     ( Fail1.hs, Fail1.o )

> runhaskell Fail2
_
```

The program now hangs forever, with `ghc.exe` consuming 100% of one CPU core. What the heck?

It gets better though:

```
> ghc -O2 --make Fail2
[2 of 2] Compiling Main     ( Fail2.hs, Fail2.o )

> runhaskell Fail2

Access violation in generated code when reading 0xffffffffffffffff

 Attempting to reconstruct a stack trace...

   Frame        Code address
 * 0x71fdd90    0x3d7ce28 C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.3\bin\ghc.exe+0x397ce28
```

Er... wat?

Ironically, if I just run `Fail2.exe` itself, it works perfectly:

```
> Fail2
7
```

What in the heck is going on? Am I going mad? This really, really looks like some kind of GHC bug. Can anyone else reproduce this, or is it just my system?

```
> ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.3
```

(Wow, OK. That really doesn't display much info. I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, and I *believe* I've installed the 64-bit build of GHC.)

Comment: Do you see a difference between `runhaskell Fail2` and `runhaskell Fail2.hs`? Once you've built a `Fail2` executable, `runhaskell` might be trying to interpret it as a Haskell source file.

Comment: Do you have any better luck with GHC 8.6.5?

Comment: Trying the one with access violation on a Linux machine gives me `Fail2:1:1: error: lexical error at character '\DEL'` followed by some binary garbage. I think @user11228628 's guess is pretty accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is a bug in GHC and it has been fixed in GHC 8.6.4.**

I have tested it with GHC 8.6.3, GHC 8.6.4 and GHC 8.6.5 and the latter two versions work as expected.

I used the x64 Windows [haskell stack](https://www.stackage.org/), and I'm running Windows 10 with all updates installed (as of 2019-05-25.)

(For all GHC versions: wether I write `runhaskell Fail2` or `runhaskell Fail2.hs` doesn't make any difference.)

### GHC 8.6.3

this works:

```sh
stack --resolver lts-13.11 runhaskell Fail2
```

then I compile Fail1:

```sh
stack --resolver lts-13.11 ghc -- -O2 --make Fail1
```

then the original runhaskell command hangs when running Fail2.

then I compile Fail2:

```sh
stack --resolver lts-13.11 ghc -- -O2 --make Fail2
```

then the original runhaskell command crashes, just like the question describes it.

### GHC 8.6.4

With `--resolver lts-13.19` (which uses GHC 8.6.4), the commands all work as expected.

### GHC 8.6.5

The same for `--resolver lts-13.23` (which uses GHC 8.6.5).

## Solution

Just update to the newest GHC version, or at least update to ghc 8.6.4 .

Comment: I see there's a new release of Haskell Platform available. Installing this fixes the issue. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is the particular issue on the GHC bug tracker?

Comment: @JeremyList: I have no idea. And I don't know how to check it, other than manually searching through hundreds of issues.

Comment: I did take a look at the release notes, and didn't see anything about such a bug having been fixed...